# How do I use php to get a listing of the tables and rows in a mysql database? (Noob here)

Tags: php, mysql

So I have a mysql db, and I've connected to it, but I'm not sure how to print out the table/row contents in php. I have sort of figured out how to print out the results of queries and I've gotten "SHOW TABLES;" to print but I want the row contents to be printed too. Anyone know how? Here's what I have now for printing out queries:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($i)){
    foreach($row as $cname => $cvalue){
        echo $cname. ":". $cvalue";
    }
}
```

Comment: loop the tables `select *`

Comment: @Dagon ? a bit confused by that answer.. I know what select * is but is that supposed to be my query or something in the loop? (sorry for stupidity)

Comment: @bard_the_dragon read this article http://codular.com/php-mysqli it will explain what you are looking for. The query that Dagon pointed out is 'select * from TABLENAME' and is the query that should be executed.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php Look at example 2. It's well documented. @bard_the_dragon

Answer (score 1):

so you want a table that shows your requested data. You could make a HTML table by using the `<table> </table>`. then you can just echo out the row and fill in the fields. you must make a loop though to go through all the data stored in your `$row`

`echo <tr> <td> the value you want </td> </tr>;`

the `<tr> </tr>` are the rows and the `<td> </td>` are the fields. ofcourse you can add as many fields and rows you want. So the end product would look something like this.

```
 `<table>
    <?php 
        foreach(your condition)
        {
            echo 
                <tr> 
                    <td> value you want in this field of the row </td> 
                    <td> second value you </td>
                </tr>;
        }
    ?>
</table>`
```

let me know if this is the solution you were searching for and if not give me some more info maybe i can come up with another solution:).
Btw this is my first post/aswer so if i f***** something up with the layout teach me senpai:D.

Answer (score 0):

You can use information_schema to get all columns for each table of the current database :

```
select table_name, column_name
from information_schema.columns
where table_schema = database()
```